# mysqli_set_charset does not store arabic letters

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I would like to store all the entered information that are written in Arabic in the database. Throughout my searching, I found out that I have to change the collation to `utf8_general_ci` and in the code I have to put the following statement: `mysqli_set_charset($dbh,"utf8");`

I gave it try but it didn't work. It still stores the entered information like this `&#1607;&#1604;&#1575;`

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It still stores the entered information like this `&#1607;&#1604;&#1575;`

it is not mysqli but your own code.
most likely you are running `htmlentities()` on your data.

Better don't use HTML formatting for storing data in database at all, or at least change it go `htmlspecialchars()`